# Animations rendered using SpriteSheet on a SpriteStage are not displayed properly

Tags: javascript, canvas, createjs

I am using the sprite sheet builder to generate a `SpriteSheet` type object from a generic MovieClip. After that, I use the `SpriteSheet` to create a Sprite type of object, containing a timeline, which I add to a `SpriteStage` like this:

```
 var spriteStage = new createjs.SpriteStage(canvas);
 var sprite = new createjs.Sprite(spriteSheet);
 spriteStage.addChild(sprite);
 sprite.play();
 createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", spriteStage);
```

**The problem** is: what results from this is a broken animation. It looks like only a few of the frames are displayed and the animation is either looping those few frames very fast or not doing anything at all.

Using `console.log(sprite.currentFrame)` on the tick update function I can see that all the frames are incremented at a rate of 30 per second, but what is actually displayed does not correspond with this.

Please note that this works well using a normal `Stage` to add and play the `Sprite` animation. Also, according to `Chrome://gpu`, the WebGL is enabled, so that is not the issue either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SpriteStage requires SpriteContainers, which reference a single image that sprites can use.
http://www.createjs.com/docs/easeljs/classes/SpriteContainer.html

It is an older WebGL approach --so  you might be interested in StageGL, a new EaselJS approach which we are beta testing and should be released soon. Basically it works the same as Stage, but accepts way more content (and is way faster!). Note that your approach above is more inline with how StageGL works.

There is a branch in GitHub: https://github.com/CreateJS/EaselJS/tree/StageGL-beta

We are still polishing up docs and demos (which has been delayed due to other priorities), but hope to get this tagged soon.

Comment: Thank you, StageGL looks very interesting, I will look into it shortly. One other thing though. When I tried the approach with `SpriteContainer` added to the stage, I realised I can only add to it objects like sprites that only use one image. In this case, how can I add animated objects to the 'SpriteStage'?

Comment: That is a limitation of the SpriteContainer/SpriteStage approach. Sprites use SpriteSheets, which allow you to animate the same way you do with regular stage. What kind of animations are you trying to do?

Comment: I usually have generic MovieClips as animated objects. But since they are made out of Shapes mostly, they can be very expensive to render. That is why, until now, I used a method to iterate through and cache their children and the performance hit remained minimal, while the objects were still being animated. But the apps are getting more and more complex, so I was looking to an even more efficient way to play animations. Sprite sheets seem like the answer, but they are significantly more complicated to implement than just exported Flash graphics.

Comment: Turning vectors into SpriteSheets can be good, but very costly in terms of memory, especially for large shapes. Check out the EaselJS SpriteSheetBuilder for run-time conversion of MovieClips. Note that when they are too complex, it might just be better to use vectors.

Comment: Yes, I have concluded as well that it may be best in the end to stick with the standard vectors, when dealing with complex MovieClips, since the memory consumption gets pretty large. Since I always use the `cache()` method for shapes and MovieClips, the performance hit is non-existent on Desktop browsers. The main issue is that I make the apps mainly for mobile devices. I guess that this is the limit of HTML5 vs native environment, for now.